# wordpress iis6 permalink /%postname%/ doesnt work IIRF url rewrite needed?

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting, permalinks, iirf

I have a wordpress site on iis6 and I want this:**php?id=6** to look like this:  **/postname/**.  When I change the permalink I get a 404 error. I have the IIRF proxy extension enabled, and in my root directory I have a IIRF.ini with the following code:

```
RedirectRule ^/blog/index\.php/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [I,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/blog/(?!index\.php|wp-|xmlrpc)(.*)$ /blog/index.php/$1 [I,L]
```

Is this code incorrect for a permalink of just /%postname%/?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just installed IIRF 2.1 on Windows Server 2003 running IIS6.

Your address seems to have /blog/ on the very beginning, but I'm afraid we can do it simpler. Bellow, follow my whole Iirf.ini, with a simple permalink working:

```
# Iirf.ini
#
# ini file for IIRF
#

RewriteEngine ON
StatusInquiry ON
IterationLimit 5

# this will allow ugly URLs to not be processed at all
RewriteRule ^/(?!index.php)(?!wp)([^\.]*)$ /index.php/$1 [I]
```

Make sure this simple form works, and then add /blog/.

Some literature that may help (it helped me)

- http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/49492102-e623-40d7-9dc3-d1411800be80.htm
- http://codehill.com/2009/11/wordpress-permalinks-in-windows-using-iirf/

Cheers!